# How to highlight a row over a column range

Tags: excel, vba

I working on a sheet that looking up the value in column D and compares that value to another sheet in another workbook to see if it is in there as well. If the value is in the other sheet then the loop moves to the next cell in column D. If it is not, then I want to highlight the row of which that value is located but only the cells that contain information (A:CU). I cannot seem to get it right.

The code I have so far highlights the row of the cell where the value was not found in the other sheet. The problem is it highlights the entire row. I know this is because of the `.EntireRow` but I am not sure how to only highlight the the cells I need.

```
Sub check()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim WorkingTab As Worksheet
    Dim PerDay24 As Workbook
    Dim CurrentOrderCalendar As Workbook

    Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set PerDay24 = Sheet1.Parent

    Set CurrentOrderCalendar = Workbooks.Open("M:\Projects\D9#s Purging\Current Order Calendar - Copy.xlsx")
    Set WorkingTab = Worksheets("working tab")

    k = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    j = WorkingTab.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 2 To k
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WorkingTab.Range(WorkingTab.Cells(2, 1), WorkingTab.Cells(j, 1)), Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value) > 0 Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 100).Value = "Active"
        Else
                Sheet1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 65535

        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

I expect for the code to highlight columns A:CU on row i when the IF statement is false.

Comment: `Sheet1.Range("A" & i & ":CU" & i).Interior.Color`.

Comment: You may want to `Dim` `i`, `j` and `k` as `Long` as Excel allows for more rows than `Integer` can handle